# How do I check what version of java im using in c++

Tags: java, c++, unit-testing, version, cxxtest

I have a testing script that checks what version of java the user is using and then executes some commands.  But we are trying to convert all of our testing into cxxtests.  I would like to know how to convert my version checking script into c++ code.  I know I could just use the system() command but I would like that to be a last resort.  Any help or leads would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the system() command, or a C++ library that will use the system() command.  This task is much better done in a shell script than C++ code.  If necessary, the shell script can call C++ code to do notifications, or whatever it is that's causing the reliance on C++.